# Find **Pontrjagin dual.** of $\Bbb Z_n$ & $\Bbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group.  Consider the set $Hom(G,\Bbb C^*)$ of homomorphisms from $G$ to $\Bbb C^*$.
>
> Define a binary operation $+:Hom(G,\Bbb C^*)\times Hom(G,\Bbb C^*)\to Hom(G,\Bbb C^*)$ s.t 
>   $$(f_1+f_2)(g)=(f_1 (g))(f_2 (g)).$$
>
> This group $(Hom(G,\Bbb C^*),+)$ is called the **Pontrjagin dual.**

Now my questions are:

**1) What is $ Hom(\Bbb Z_n,\Bbb C^*)$??**

**2) What is $ Hom(\Bbb Z,\Bbb C^*)$??**

> My intuition is:

1) we can construct $\phi:\Bbb Z_n \to \Bbb C^*$ then $Im(\phi)\le n $

Again $\Bbb Z_n/{\ker \phi} \cong Im(\phi)$.

Some finite subgroups of $\Bbb C^*$ are in $S^1$, i.e.,

$\phi:\Bbb Z_n \to S^1$ s.t $x \mapsto e^{2x\frac{\pi}{n}} $, if $n$ is not prime then we can construct more like this also in each case we have the trivial homomorphism.

So are these the only possibilities or there are more?? Again prove whatever your conclusion is.

2) Same like 1) here we can construct $\phi:\Bbb Z \to S^1$ s.t $x \mapsto e^{2x\frac{\pi}{r}} $ , where $r \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$. What next now??

Comment: Do you mean to send $1$ to something in both cases, instead of $x$? If so: @1: why couldn't you send it to any root of unity? It looks like that would still be a homomorphism. Similarly @2: Why $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and not $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: No I am not saying that. I told that it is my intution. We have to find $Hom(Z_n,C^*)$ & $Hom(Z,C^*)$. So find it..

Comment: Although the dual is defined as the group of **homomorphisms**, it seems that you're trying to consider only **embeddings** $G \hookrightarrow C^*$.

Comment: @HSN And why do you send $1$ by the way?? Will it make any difference?? Just watch my calculation I have explicitly written those homomorphisms...

Comment: @ Sammy Black for embedding we need injective maps. But I have not mentioned it. See the definition of Pontrjagin dual.

Comment: What I meant to say is that any of these homomorphisms is entirely determined by the image of $1$, due to the fact that it is a homomorphism. It is therefore conventional to explicitly give a homomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as domain, by just giving the image of $1$. For an intuition, it is rather good already, though. I have to agree with @SammyBlack though, your intuition seems to be somewhat restricted to injections.

Comment: It is spelt *Pontryagin*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi: \Bbb{Z}_n \to \Bbb{C}^*$, put $z = \phi(1) \in \Bbb{C}^*$.  Then,
\begin{align}
z^n &= \underbrace{\phi(1) \cdot \cdots \cdot \phi(1)}_{n} \\
&= \underbrace{(\phi + \cdots + \phi)}_{n}(1) \\
&= (n\phi)(1) \\
&= \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb{Z}_n}(1) \\
&= 1,
\end{align}
so $z$ is an $n$-th [root of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).  By the fundamental theorem of algebra, there are exactly $n$ of these.  If $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then $z = \zeta^k$ for some $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$.  This parametrizes possible values of $z$, so the dual is a group of size $n$.

It turns out that the dual group is cyclic, so
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}_n, \Bbb{C}^*) \cong \Bbb{Z}_n.
$$
Why?  Say that $\psi: \Bbb{Z}_n \to \Bbb{C}^*$ with $\psi(1) = \zeta$, a primitive $n$-th root of unity.  Then, the following calculation shows that any other $\phi: \Bbb{Z}_n \to \Bbb{C}^*$ is a multiple of $\psi$:
$$
\phi(1) = \zeta^k = \bigl( \psi(1) \bigr)^k = (k\psi)(1),
$$
and any homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is uniquely determined by where it sends $1$.

---

The case of $\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}, \Bbb{C}^*)$ is easier.  Any homomorphism $\phi: \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{C}^*$ is uniquely determined by $z = \phi(1)$.  Unlike the case of the **finite** cyclic group, there are no restrictions on $z \in \Bbb{C}^*$.  Thus,
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}, \Bbb{C}^*) \cong \bigl( \Bbb{C}^*, \times \bigr).
$$